# Ember: tab component with refresh button

Tags: ember.js

I have a tab component (similar to Bootstrap's tabs) in Ember, where every tab can be clickable but also has a refresh button next to the label. The problem I have is that whenever I click the refresh button to trigger the `refresh` action the `switchTab` action to open the tab is also triggered, because they are nested. Since the actions don't know anything about each other, how do you trigger the correct action (or cancel the incorrect one?)

```
<li class="tab" {{action 'switchTab' tab}}>
    <span {{action 'refresh' tab}}>Refresh&nbsp;</span>
    Bubble Bobble Tab
</li>
```

One option is to separate the label into its own span and put the `switchTab` on that element, but that would mean that only the label was clickable (without a lot more css), which is a bad user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Samuel, You can use `bubbles=false` inside the action helper if you do not want the action to bubble upward. For example,

> ```
> <li class="tab" {{action 'switchTab'}}>
> <span {{action 'refresh' bubbles=false}}>Refresh&nbsp;</span>
> Bubble Bobble Tab </li>
> ```

http://ember-twiddle.com/b8d2b88cf5b18b613fd2

Comment: @SamuelLindblom It kinda makes sense tho . http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/actions/#toc_stopping-event-propagation